# How can I store a very long hex sequence?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, nsstring, hex

Suppose I have a list of pictures to show, and I fetched a hex sequences in string like:

```
"0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef..."
```

which in binary format is:

```
0000 0001 0010 0011 ...
```

here `1` means that **picture can be shown(YES)**, and `0` means **picture should not be shown(NO)**.

So in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, I can use it like:

```
if (hexData & (1 << rowID))
  // show picture
else
  // do nothing
```

to show relevant picture for tableViewCells.
So how can I store this hex sequence?

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

I'd store it in na `NSString` and use `characterAtIndex:` to get each hex number. NSString should be able to hold very long sequences like the one you showed.

Edit:

```
unichar test = 'f'; // sample unichar
NSString *digit = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0x%c", test];
unsigned int number = 0;
[[NSScanner scannerWithString:digit] scanHexInt:&number];
```

After this, `number` will contain the value of the hex number in `test`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I did it before, however, `NSString` wastes a lot of bits..I just need one bit for each row checking... :(

Comment: That might have problems with A-F values.

Comment: char type is perfect, for you can check it's bits with bitwise operators.

Comment: How can i check char's bits with bitwise operators? Can you give a simple example? I use `charData & 0xf` and `0-9` is okay, but as you said, `a-f`'s value is wrong.

Comment: I've edited my response with some code that helps you extract he values you need;

Comment: Oh, thanks for your code! But I've asked a related question [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9171380/how-can-i-convert-a-hex-string-to-a-hex-array)..I need a better solution.. :S